# Resources/Reading Materials on PASA (optimal control theory)

Tags: differential-equations, oc.optimization-and-control, mathematical-modeling, online-resources, mathematical-biology

I am currently working on my undergraduate thesis, and my adviser suggested that I look into a Polyhedral Active Set Algorithm (PASA) for my paper. I have been trying to find resources/materials on it online, but most of the papers I have seen and read unfortunately seem to be accessible only to graduate students. So, I would just like to ask for resources on PASA that can be accessed by undergrads? If there are no such materials, then how can an undergraduate student learn this algorithm or what's a good reading list/pathway to being able to understand it? I do sincerely think that it would be a great fit for my chosen topic. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2022 article [A Gradient-Based Implementation of the Polyhedral Active Set Algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.05353) discusses one particular PASA implementation in much detail --- it does not seem to require much by way of background knowledge (other than familiarity with conjugate gradient algorithms).

You can download their PASA code from the SuiteOpt package at https://people.clas.ufl.edu/hager/software
Trying out the code might actually be an efficient way to get started.